# Android : app takes few seconds to startup when i compile external libraries

Tags: android, performance, libraries, startup

My app does not start up instantly, it takes few seconds to show the **first activity**, which is only content my app **logo** text.

I'm using two external libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
```

and I don't use them on my **first activity**, it's just a logo `activity`.

so why I'm having this issue?

Comment: the problem is present also in release build?

Comment: Unfortunately, Yes , and it drives me crazy.

Comment: if you remove these libs it starts instantly? have you identified which of them is causing your problem?

Comment: when i remove any of them , my app gets better like 50% , if i remove both of them my app starts instantly .

Comment: have you tried this? https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview-walkthru.html

Comment: If you have enabled instant run in android studio, it can cause this problem. If enabled, try disabling it.

Comment: yes i actually did enable it , let me guess how to disable it.

Comment: that didn't work too.

Comment: so external libraries has nothing to do with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is called **[Cold starts](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html)**

follow below link for avoid  **Cold starts**

http://blog.androiduithemes.com/avoiding-cold-starts-on-android/

http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts